# Deleting the keys and values in NSDictionaries more than the value 100.000 kilometers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am having a trouble with NSDictionary am adding value as a kilo meters and name as a key this is how am giving

```
NSDictionary * dd = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:locationKMArray forKeys:nameArray];
NSLog(@"%@",dd);
```

This is how outputs looks like

```
name1 = 1.011115;
name2 = 55.14256;
name3 = 150.48752;
name4 = 22.48668;
:
:
```

looks like this now i want to print only less than 100.000 kilo meters how can i do this

Comment: it not google, try yourself. If any error occur than we help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the `dd` as below:

```
NSSet *keys = [dd keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *key, NSNumber *obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return obj.floatValue < 10000;
}];
NSLog(@"%@", keys);

[keys enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@", dd[key]);
}];
```

Comment: Please tickmark on right button so, it will be helpful to others.

Comment: Okay i will give you but can you please tell me that the data to be printed in the form of name1 = 5.432 ; name2 = 80.4478 ; .... like this now you have given to print the names only but i want with the values also

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [@{@"name1":@"1.011115 km",@"name2":@"55.14256 km",@"name3":@"150.48752 km",@"name4":@"22.48668 km"}mutableCopy];
for (NSString* key in dic) {
    NSString *value = [dic objectForKey:key];
    NSArray *array = [value componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    double km = [[array objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

    if (km > 100) {
        [dic removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",dic);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:locationKMArray forKeys:nameArray];
NSArray*keys=[dict allKeys];
for (NSString* key in keys) {
    int km = [dict objectForKey:key];
    if (km > 10000) {
        NSLog(@"%d" km);
    }
}
```

I don't know if you entered the kms actually with the "km" string or just as ints or longs. Adjust as needed.

Regards